# JavaScript Regex not accepting any key

Tags: javascript

When i add `+@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;` this code to this `/^[\ba-zA-Z\s-\.\_]` in email field in form not accepting any key.

```
function mailonly(e){

var code;
if (!e) var e = window.event;
if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
else if (e.which) code = e.which;
var character = String.fromCharCode(code);
    var AllowRegex  =/^[\ba-zA-Z\s-\.\_]



+@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;

    if (AllowRegex.test(character)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: And you think this is a correct email validation regex ? Nope.

Comment: http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

Comment: `if (!e) var e = window.event;` - you probably meant `if (!e) e = window.event;`

Comment: @Kos: does that change anything?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the dash when in a character class (or put it at the beginning/end of the class):

```
/^[\ba-zA-Z\s\-\.\_]    or    /^[\ba-zA-Z\s\.\_-]
```

No need to escape the other chars by the way:

```
/^[\ba-zA-Z\s._-]
```

And the `\b` has nothing to do here:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\s._-]
```

The remaining part of the regex looks fine.

But don't try to validate an email with a regex. You could simply use `/.+@.+/` for example, while sending a confirmation email containing a link that will validate the account.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said your regex will not validate email addresses properly. But the specific problem you are encountering is most likely that you are not escaping the '-' character between \s and . in the first part of your regex. The regex interpreter will be trying to read it as the range \s-. which of course is not anything.

sp00m beat me too it. As well as getting rid of \b I'd imagine you don't want to match \s in the first part of an email address, you also should be matching 0-9 in that part.